# Were the Soviet soldiers in Afghanistan officially volunteers?

Tags: military, soviet-union, cold-war

I always thought they were conscripts, who were ordered to go there, but recently saw a mention that they all were volunteers. So, I wonder whether they signed any paper of consent before being sent there?

Comment: Please [edit] to avoid problems of the kind: ["is it true"](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2132/26786), ["someone once said"](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2125/26786), and [please document your preliminary research"](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2125/26786).

Comment: Got curious about this. I looks like the SU *did* have conscription at the time. However, that doesn't mean conscripts were sent there. I understand the modern Russian state at least has restrictions on conscripts being sent out of the country's borders (which supposedly is part of what's behind the upcoming efforts to officially annex captured Ukrainian territory).  Some of the [references listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_Soviet_Union#References) might be useful for someone looking into this further.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, USSR did have the conscription at that time (actually, since at least 1930s and until its dissolution in 1991). And, yes, some conscripts were sent to Afghanistan (and died there).

Comment: An interesting article on JSTOR [Manning the Soviet Military](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2538691?read-now=1&seq=27#page_scan_tab_contents) from 1982 discusses the history and structure of the Soviet forces in the early 80s. Estimates 70-75% conscripts, 25 to 30% career.

Comment: there's a difference between volunteering and "volunteering". In the military (in most nations) the latter is way more common than the first. IOW if you sign up for something nasty you're getting some preferential treatment (nicer stationing, shorter term in theater, promise of early promotion, etc.), if you don't you get sent anyway and get the shitty jobs.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the question is, did they sign a paper of agreement to go there.

Comment: @justCal, the question is whether the conscripts had to sign up for trip to Afghanistan

Comment: @jwenting indeed, so my question is about the later.

Comment: @jwentig still, the USSR was not modern Russia, and officially sanctioned signature forgery was not widely practiced there.

Comment: I think the bit a lot of the commenters aren't getting (likely because its not A Thing in most western militaries) is the bit about conscripts not being allowed to be deployed outside of Russian (and Soviet?) borders. So for instance the *overall* makeup of the Soviet military may not be relevant to the question, since military leaders may not have been free to deploy conscripts anywhere they wanted to.

Comment: @T.E.D. I think, it is only Putin's verbal promise. Definitely there was no such law or regulation in the USSR. Still they could feel uneasy sending conscripts to a controversial war abroad without their consent. One thing to support this version is that the soldiers in Afghanistan were called "warriors-internationalists". This may hint they signed some paper about "internationalist duty"

Comment: @Anixx - Hmmm. Looking over [this](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/explainer-russian-conscription-reserve-and-mobilization), it does appear that the laws in this matter are indeed only that they can't be deployed into combat with less than 4 months training, unless martial law is declared, or there's been a general mobilization (the latter of which is exactly what they're doing right now). *Current* law isn't really on topic here though, and I'd imagine you have access to much better Russian-language sources than I do English language ones.

Comment: All Chinese forces in Korea were officially not only volunteers but were not even in the Chinese army. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Volunteer_Army So I would not be surprised if the USSR claimed something remotely similar for deployment abroad.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Russian journalist and politician Mark Feygin](https://youtu.be/mnVT6Zh2dvI?t=2839), indeed one had to write a request to be sent to Afghanistan, at least, after the death of Brezhnev.

Comment: I do not have time to watch the entire video, but does he provide any references? He is a professional lawyer and did not serve in Afghanistan himself (he was 18 when the Soviet troops pulled out).

Comment: @MoisheKohan the link is with timecode, pointing exactly at this claim.

Comment: I see, so no references.